ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'llama_index.llms.huggingface'
Recently encountered this error while importing HuggingFaceLLM from llama_index.llms. Turns out llama_index keeps updating. Following is the recent mode of importing the said package:
pip install llama-index-llms-huggingface
from llama_index.llms.huggingface import HuggingFaceLLM

Open to know any automated way of tracing updates and avoiding the search for the cause of errors in library import.

The syntax for importing PromptTemplate has also similarly changed - i.e. from llama_index.core import PromptTemplate

Hugging Face LLMs
As of 2nd Sept 2024, LlamaIndex wraps into:
pip install llama-index-llms-huggingface
pip install llama-index-llms-huggingface-api

Try installing the above command to solve this issue.
